# DB View in DB project in Visual Studio can't see synonym in same project

Tags: database, visual-studio, project

Our web app uses 4 databases, all on the same server.

The SQL for these databases is stored in 4 projects in our solution.

I have a view in one database that is used in two other databases.

Both of those databases have a synonym to the view, WITH THE SAME NAME.  From a database perspective, it makes perfect sense.

[database_1].dbo.Syn_AAAAAA and [database_2].dbo.Syn_AAAAAA both point to [database_3].dbo.vw_AAAAAA.

From a sql server perspective, it makes perfect sense.

Application works fine.  Databases are quite happy.

Database1 uses the [synonym ==> view] in stored procedures, and everything is fine.  When the code is in the db project, it is fine too.

In database2 PROJECT, I reference the [synonym ==> view] in another view.  Of course, works fine in the data base.

BUT in the *project*, the view that uses the synonym is choking.  It's like it is seeing ALL synonyms with that name, even those outside of it's scope, the database it's in.

```
select y.columnA, y.columnB, y.columnC, _l.columnD_, d3.columnE, d3.columnF
        from dbo.TableD d3
       inner join (subquery) y
          on y.columnA = d3.columnA
        left join _dbo.syn_AAAAAA_ l
          on _l.columnC_ = d3.columnC
```

(Underscores denote the error locations from IntelliSense.)

If I can write competent SQL code on the server, why do I have to fight with Visual Studio about storing it in a project?

SQL71501: View: [dbo].[vw_AAAAAA] contains an unresolved reference to an object.
Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects:
[$(ThisDB)].[dbo].[Syn_BBBBBB].[l]::[ColumnName],
[$(ThisDB)].[dbo].[Syn_BBBBBB].[ColumnName] or
[dbo].[Table].[l]::[ColumnName].

SQL71561: View: [dbo].[vw_AAAAAA] has an unresolved reference to object
[$(ThisDB)].[dbo].[Syn_BBBBBB]

Comment: `the view that uses the synonym refuses to see the synonym` have you added the synonym in the first place? `why do I have to fight with Visual Studio` if you forgot to create the synonym on the server, you'd get errors there as well

Comment: `I reference the [synonym==>view] in another view.` reference how? Did you add a database reference? Did you modify the name to use the server/database variables? This question is missing the actual code, the error information, project references, project structure. People have to guess what may be the problem

Comment: I must say, I fail to see any advantage to including the db design as a project in a solution.  Much easier to work in SQL DB on the machine, rather than trying to tie all 63 of these projects together.

Comment: Without a DB project you have to wait until deplooyment to production to find problems like bad names or types. You have no version control over the database and no way to deploy *changes* to an already deployed database.

Comment: On the other hand, database references can be a pain in schema comparisons. They appear as differences and if you apply the changes to your project, the're lost without warning. This can be a real problem with cross-database queries, views and stored procedures. At least with synonyms you can put all such references in one place

Answer (score 0):

Problem lay with the **SYNONYM**.

CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[syn_xxxx] FOR [*DBName*].[dbo].[vw_xxxx]

Had to change it to

CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[syn_xxxx] FOR **[$(DBNameVariable)]**.[dbo].[vw_xxxx]

Most of the time [DBName] worked, but in this case I had to use the [$(DBNameVariable)].

right click on your db reference, look at the database you're trying to reference, and see if there is a variable for it.  (I didn't set this up, so it's a little outside my experience.)  My last position, we didn't keep SQL projects in our code solution.

Hard to imagine a fully qualified reference is causing a problem, and requires a DBVariable to work.

That is to say,

> DatabaseName.dbo.SynonymName

is wrong, and

> [($DatabaseNameVariable)].dbo.SynonymName

is the way to go.

Comment: The view works in the data base.  The problem is the 4 db projects in the solution are tripping all over themselves.  I had to fully qualify my synonym to tell the view, "Look in your own database for this synonym"  dbo.syn_xxxx is sufficient on SQL Server, but the project was getting tangled up with itself.

Comment: `we didn't keep SQL projects in our code solution.` you have to keep the database source somewhere though, for version control, diffing , deployment and testing *before* you actually deploy to production. A SQL Project is essentially a script of the entire database. You'd have to do the same thing no matter what solution you chose. Compiling to `dacpac` and deployment are great benefits, but the SQL Project is actually a project of SQL scripts